# do i have to install aptana studio plugin for eclipse PDT?

Tags: php, eclipse, codeigniter, aptana, eclipse-pdt

currently i am working on a code igniter and using eclipse PDT for it .. as i google it and some says that add aptana plugin with eclipse is best. so i just want 2 ask you should i have to install aptana plugin for eclipse PDT .what difference should it make. or what should i do more to make eclipse even better for php or code igniter.?
and one more thing if let say i installed the plugin ,is the syntax coloring also get change.? as i like the syntax coloring of aptana studio rather then eclipse?

Answer (score 5):

"some says that add aptana plugin with eclipse is best"

[image: XKCD: Real programmers]

Bottom Line: Use the editor you feel most comfortable with

Comment: i think you are not a programmer or may b there is a chance that u r not familiar with php.. so boy this is not place for you. you should visit yahoo answers. you will definitely get goodd ratings there

Comment: He's only the 3rd-place user in the top of "most [tag:php] answers": http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/topusers . You have made it obvious, that you are real programmer, unlike Gordon.